# How do I fix this jQuery additive selector?

Tags: jquery

Given a table row, I want to get the HTML out of the span element that's in the last td in a row.

I ended up with:

```
$row.children("td:last").children("span:first").html();
```

I tried:

```
$row.children("td:last > span").html();
```

and

```
$row.children("td:last span").html();
```

But neither worked.  Is there a way to crunch this into a single selector statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$row.find(" > td:last > span:first").html()
```

The first arrow in the `find()` means it will only look at immediate children of `$row` to find the last `<td>`. It's equivalent to: `$row.children("td:last")` but using `find()` gives you the extra flexibility to continue searching deeper.

Comment: What does the first arrow in the find statement mean?

Comment: that means it will only look at immediate children of $row to find the last td. it's equivalent to: `$row.children("td:last")` but using `find` gives you the extra flexibility to continue searching deeper

Answer (score 1):

Are there multiple spans?  If so, the major difference between the one that worked and the others is that the others are missing the ":first" instruction.

Also, if you use the **find** method instead, things are likely to work better.  The "children" method doesn't necessarily hunt down deeper in the tree.

Comment: +1 for pointing out why find works better.  Only 1 span, though, to answer your question.